# selenoid and specflowplus runner : how do they work togather

Tags: specrun, selenoid

I am using selenoid  with ggr and 10 hosts. per my understanding ggr devides the load to all the host machine based on quota.

my question is if in .srprofile I have thread count as 5 , will 50 scenario will be executed at once ( 5 threads will be invoked per hosts)

I am not clear how does that work with selenoid.

Answer (score 0):

Every request to create a new browser will cause Ggr to randomly choose a host and create a session there. Overall sessions distribution is quasi-uniform. If every thread is sending new session request to Ggr then only 5 browser sessions will be created in parallel.